# Replace core data model in new version of app without having previous source code

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

Hi I struck at core data migration issue. I have developed a app which is new version of an existing app in Appstore. But i don't have source code of previous version and don't know exactly that whether core data was used in old version or not. So how to update my app (which has core data) to Appstore without any crashes. Any quick solution please?

Comment: If you don't know whether the old version uses Core Data, how are you expecting to migrate the old data? Or are you just throwing away / ignoring any old data?

Comment: I want to ignore my old data if exist.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention in a comment that you want to ignore the old data, you don't need to do any kind of migration. Model migration is about updating existing data to work with a newer data model. The only danger would be if the old app used Core Data **and** your new app attempts to use a persistent store file with the same file name. Then your app would attempt to load the old data, since it would find that file with the correct name.

The easiest way to test this is:

1. Install the existing app (from the app store)
2. Use this app until you're sure it's saving some data
3. Install the new version from Xcode. Since it's an upgrade, it will overwrite the app store copy.

By then you'll know exactly what happens when upgrading. If you get a Core Data related crash, change your Core Data setup to use a different filename. Then delete the app from your iOS device and repeat the test from above.

Comment: Better to have code that deletes the existing database files on first-launch, if necessary.  Don't leave litter in your sandbox.

Comment: If you know what those files are named. Doesn't sound like that's the case here.

Comment: You can check the sandbox.

Comment: @Avi if you feel that you have a better answer, please don't hesitate to post one.